# Xcode 9 Debug View Hierarchy extremely slow

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode9, view-hierarchy

Before Xcode 9, Debug View Hierarchy completely created a visual interactive representation of the UI in about two seconds. Now, in Xcode 9, it takes about 15 seconds.

Is there any setting to make it fast as it used to be?

Comment: Not AFAIK. As an aside and in its defense, Xcode 9 is doing more with "view debugging", e.g. building a hierarchy of not only the views, but also the active view controller hierarchy (which can be helpful to see as well), too.

Comment: Have you filed a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com ?

Comment: @wolfrevo nope. personally, I did file reports in the past and I haven't got any responses or fixes to any of my reports, so to be honest I gave up.